# gitlab 6.0 Lost Project After Upgrade

Tags: git, repository, gitlab

After upgrading from Gitlab v5.4 to v6.0 I have completely lost a project that has been active used and pushed to for 5 months.  I performed a backup prior to the upgrade, I just can't find anything about restoring missing projects after an upgrade.  Can someone help?

Here is an excerpt to show that everything is up-and-running:

```
:/home/git/gitlab$ sudo service gitlab start
The Unicorn web server already running with pid 29977, not restarting.
The Sidekiq job dispatcher is already running with pid 29998, not restarting
The GitLab Unicorn webserver with pid 29977 is running.
The GitLab Sidekiq job dispatcher with pid 29998 is running.
GitLab and all it's components are up and running.
```

The problem is only related to the most recent project that has been created.  I still have the others prior to this newest one that is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Its because of the namespaces. For some reason the groups/namespaces did not get activated when I did the upgrade. Therefore, the projects that were previously associated with those namespaces did not get presented on the main page. Once I reactivated the namespaces (app-development, and web-development) and assigned the missing project to one of those, everything works again... phew that was very close!

By the way, something like this is covered at the end of the upgrade docs in gitlab: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/update/5.4-to-6.0.md

Answer (score 2):

You can restore backups with rake:

```
rake gitlab:backup:restore
```

However, GitLab does a check to ensure that you can only restore when you're on the same version (actually, by commit hash), so you'd have to downgrade GitLab first.

Was your project in the root namespace? GitLab 6.0 did away with the concept of a root namespace, so it's possible that your project was lost when you ran [`migrate_global_projects`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/update/5.4-to-6.0.md#5-install-libs-migrations-etc), especially if [the project's owner had a project in his or her namespace with the same name.](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/update/5.4-to-6.0.md#troubleshooting) You could fix this by rolling back the upgrade, restoring from backup, and manually moving the project to a non-global namespace.

Comment: excellent explanation, unfortunately I figured that out moments before you posted this.  Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

Though it won't have all your issue and merge request history, you could make a new project and just push it back up to your GitLab instance.

Comment: Yea, I thought about that but I have many issues that would not be associated with the project now... The only ones that I could re-associate are the ones that are "assigned to me" which still show in my issues tab; however they are not linked to any particular project...

Comment: Maybe I could get into the mysql table for the issues and re-assocate each to the new project I create?

Comment: I just found that project id that I'm looking to replace would be `2`, I can create a new project, get the new project id, and update all issues in the `issues` table where project id is `2` to whatever the new project id is... this philosophy would work the same for merge requests too if there was enough of those for me to care about

Comment: alright, interesting twist, before I did what I described above, I went into the admin area and found the project specs listed there...wtf... how can they be listed there and not in the normal projects page?

Comment: Well that's weird. Is the project private?

Comment: Figured it out! Its because of the namespaces.  For some reason the groups/namespaces did not get activated when I did the upgrade.  Therefore, the projects that were previously associated with those namespaces did not get presented on the main page.  Once I reactivated the namespaces (app-development, and web-development) and assigned the missing project to one of those, everything works again... phew that was very close!